# use datagridview to show 2 tables' data for updates in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Now I am making a C# winForm and I have to use a grid to display data retrieved from two tables for users to edit.

the tables are follows.

student table:

```
id int
name char(10)
```

subject table:

```
id int
name char(10)
```

studentsubject table:

```
id int (Pri key, AUTO_INCREMENT)
student_id int 
subject_id int 
mark int
```

The grid in the winform will show subjects of a certain student, e.g. id = 12345, with the following SQL:

```
select studentsubject.id, subject.name, studentsubject.mark
from subject, studentsubject
where studentsubject.student_id = 12345
and studentsubject.subject_id = subject.id
```

this data retrived is put into a dataset and then put into a grid with the first column (studentsubject.id) is hidden.

I used datagridview to do that and can let user change the mark, add new row for new subject and delete subject by deleting a row in the datagridview.

but the problem is how to make the changes of data from the grid back to the database.

And should I use datagrid to do instead??

thx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009857/asp-net-how-to-update-a-database-from-a-gridview-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Here are UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE commands corresponding to your requirements:

```
update studentsubject 
set mark = @mark

insert into [subject] (name) 
values (@name); 
insert into studentsubject (student_id, subject_id, mark) 
values (1, @@identity, @mark)

declare @subject_id int; 
select @subject_id = subject_id 
from studentsubject 
where id = @id; 
delete from studentsubject 
where id = @id; 
delete from [subject] 
where id = @subject_id
```

I suggest that you perform updates using the [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx), becaues it can automatically decide which operation to execute based on a DataRow's state. All you need is to execute the [SqlDataAdapter.Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.update.aspx) method. Of course, [SqlDataAdapter.DeleteCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.deletecommand.aspx), [SqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.insertcommand.aspx) and [SqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand.aspx) propertes must be assigned.

Here is a code snippet:

```
adapter.InsertCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
adapter.InsertCommand.CommandText = "insert into [subject] (name) values (@name); insert into studentsubject (student_id, subject_id, mark) values (1, @@identity, @mark)";
adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddRange(new SqlParameter[] {
    new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.Char, 10, "name"),
    new SqlParameter("@mark", SqlDbType.Int, 1, "mark")
});
adapter.UpdateCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = "update studentsubject set mark = @mark";
adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@mark", SqlDbType.Int, 1, "mark");
adapter.DeleteCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
adapter.DeleteCommand.CommandText = "declare @subject_id int; select @subject_id = subject_id from studentsubject where id = @id; delete from studentsubject where id = @id; delete from [subject] where id = @subject_id";
adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int, int.MaxValue, "id");
```